# string role = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role).Value; is returning null? why it is returning null?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, claims

**Startup.cs**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddCookie( options => {
         options.LoginPath = "/authentication/signin";
         options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
         {
            OnSigningIn = async context =>
            {
              var principal = context.Principal;

              if (principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email))
              {    
                 if (principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type ==
                       ClaimTypes.Email).Value == "admin@bookevents.com")
                  {
                    var claimsIdentity = principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     var claimsIdentity = principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

                     claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"));            
                  }
               }
               await Task.CompletedTask;
             }
        };
});

    
services.AddControllersWithViews();
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(); }
```

`Authentication` controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Signin(string email, string password)
{           
    var user = userService.Validate(email, password).Data;
        
    if (user != null)
    {
       var claims = new List<Claim>();
       claims.Add(new Claim("email", user.Email));
       claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email));
       claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.FullName));
       var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
       var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
       await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal);
       return Redirect("/BookEvent/ViewAllUserEvents/");
    }
    else
    {
       return RedirectToAction("Signin", new { status = 1 });
    }
 }
```

`BookEvent` controller:

```
public IActionResult ViewAllUserEvents()
{              
    string role = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role).Value;
    string email = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
    IEnumerable<BookEventDTO> enumBook = bookEventsService.GetUserEvents(role, email).Data;
    return View(enumBook);
}
```

Why am I not getting value from `startup.cs` when I am putting roles in claims? My signin is working well.

Answer (score 0):

It was just returning null from previous method

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).